# Why is System.Net.Http.HttpMethod a class, not an enum?

Tags: c#, language-design

`HttpStatusCode` is implemented as an `enum`, with each possible value assigned to its corresponding HTTP status code (e.g. `(int)HttpStatusCode.Ok == 200`).

However, `HttpMethod` is [implemented as a `class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod(v=vs.118).aspx), with static properties to get instances for the various HTTP verbs (`HttpMethod.Get`, `HttpMethod.Put` etc). What is the rationale behind *not* implementing `HttpMethod` as an `enum`?

Comment: Are you asking that it could have been an enum and loose the methods it has to some other class?

Comment: It could have been an enum, but then it could not support other http verbs than the standard one. There's actually a `HttpMethod` enum in the `System.Net.Cache` namespace.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) (emphasis mine):

> **Remarks**
>
> The most common usage of HttpMethod is to use one of the static properties on this class.  *However, if an app needs a different value for the HTTP method, the HttpMethod constructor initializes a new instance of the HttpMethod with an HTTP method that the app specifies.*

Which is of course not possible with an enum.

See its [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod.httpmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) and [method property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod.method(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ah, that explains it. My question was raised mainly because I reasoned that "all the allowed verbs are specified in the standard - why not just enumerate them?", but support for nonstandard verbs is, I guess, a sound consideration here. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Some additional resources about using classes with static members as an alternative to enums:

https://ardalis.com/enum-alternatives-in-c/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types

Answer (score 8):

After **years**, I suppose ***Microsoft** has heard your wish...*

Here is what you wished to have...

[HttpVerb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.httpverbs?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: Note: Requires Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core, you have the following enum

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpMethod
```