# Why is System.Net.Http.HttpMethod a class, not a struct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

There was a previous question related to an implementation point in .Net standard's `System.Net`, regarding why the `HttpMethod` was not still an enum.

[Why is System.Net.Http.HttpMethod a class, not an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717516/why-is-system-net-http-httpmethod-a-class-not-an-enum)

It has a great answer around extensiblity.

However, as I say in the title why is it not a struct?

[It seems to pass all the tests according to microsofts guidelines?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) It's a bit of info that gets thrown around an awful lot in web applications and I 'think' `DELETE` is the longest verb and comes in below the 16 bytes recommended.

Is this something to do with strings being a halfway house in .Net? I know gains might be marginal, but I just want to understand better.

Comment: The 16bytes isn´t the (only) indication for when to use the one over the other. In fact you can have structs with higher memory-allocation or classes with lower one. It´s just a **Guideline**, which you can break.

Comment: It arguably could be, it just isn't. It implements `IEquatable<>`, which, in earlier versions of the JIT, was itself a bit of a performance trap on structs due to boxing (newer versions do a better job of avoiding this where possible). Whether or not that was a concern, or whether the author(s) just didn't think about it very hard, is an open question. I doubt `HttpMethod` gets "thrown around" enough for it to *really* matter: it's copying a reference versus... copying a reference (the `string` inside), and since it's a collection of `static`s allocation doesn't matter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess I can't think of a use for a `null` method either in terms of the domain (HTTP), regardless of computer science reasons. If only C# had fixed length strings, we wouldn't have to go to the heap every time because of the variable size.

Comment: The heap is mostly irrelevant in this discussion: assuming you don't have custom methods but only use the static fields on `HttpMethod` (most common, I imagine), you're just going to be getting pre-allocated instances, each referring to an interned string. In that sense, C# *does* have "fixed length strings" -- literals are part of the string intern pool, and allocation isn't a concern there. Class or struct, `HttpMethod`is *not* copying around the actual characters in the methods. In an `unsafe` context, you can have a `char[16]` field in a struct, but this would only rarely be appropriate.

Comment: The only heap allocations to optimize in this case would be the `HttpMethod` (and accompanying strings) formed by parsing a request, on the server end. If it turned out that was necessary to optimize (which is unlikely, since it happens only once per request), it would be fairly easy to do by just not using `HttpMethod` at all, and directly comparing the characters (from a `Span`, even). That's getting really deep into micro-optimization, though, and there are likely much bigger wins to score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would not be a lot of advantages in struct over class.

Structs are perfect for memcpy / memcmp types of implementations and in case of `HttpMethod` it's not necessary.

if you look at .net core implementation https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMethod.cs you will see that it uses reference equality check to compare instances which is slightly faster than string comparison. With structs it would not be possible... Since most struct instances would actually be different instances and they would have to compare string values.

Given that HTTP method string values aren't extremely long there are really no other benefits in struct here, as it only carries one string reference and most HttpMethod instances are going to be instances of static fields of HttpMethod class.

It could also be a plain string but then it would not aid in method resolutions during compilation and such.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a pretty good reasoning. Maybe these considerations were more important that null reference type issues.